# 2D Pupil Rig with Shrinkwrap

Tags: rigging, constraints, shrinkwrap

I've been trying to build a character with basically a 2D squarish eye shape and pupil. Along with that, I want to be able to have an empty which the character's eyes will always be pointing at

My solution so far is to have a bone behind the eye and put the weight on just the pupil, parent the bone to the head, and damp track it towards the empty. Then lastly, limit the rotation to just the edges of the eye.

It's sort of worked, it looks pretty close to what I want, BUT when I go to turn the head, the pupils fly off the face. There's a mirror modifier on the eyes, which is why the left one is going crazy too, but just focusing on the right eye, the pupils always move faster than the rest of the head and eye.

1. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?
2. Is there a way easier way to do all of this?

[image: Modifiers on eyes]
[image: Tilting Head]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5wzqkor0k4mppo/Boy.blend?dl=0

Comment: I'd like to answer your question, about how to rig eyes like this, but the file you've provided has a ton of problems that make it very difficult for me to work with, and I'm concerned that my answer is going to be, "First, fix abcd and e, which I won't tell you how to do because it's not the question," and you'll be stuck on how to do any of that.  Your model should be at the world origin; meshes should have rotation and scale applied; the model should be symmetrical here, and it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! That's really helpful. I had this character as part of a whole scene. So maybe I'm misunderstanding how to do characters in the first place? Should it be separated into a different file or something? Could that be affecting things?

I'll see if I can clean up those things. I'm still pretty new to this and tutorials are all so focused on specific things that I miss a lot of bigger picture best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Nathan, there are a lot of problems to be solved, you need to import the rig and character into a new file and apply all their transforms. But. About the question you're having a so-called "Double transform", where the eye object (circle.004) is moved by the head bone (it's bone child of it) AND the eye bone is moving its vertices, resulting in a double transform, moving twice as expected.

Only one parenting should be applied in order to solve: bone parent OR Armature parent.
You could create a bone cor the cornea, a bone for the pupil, a bone for targeting (don't use empties if an armature is in use: better animate with a single armature object).

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I did all of those things and it's actually working now. Not sure which specific thing fixed it, but I'm going to guess it was all of the above. Thanks again!